# Android Studio colision entre circulo y rectangulo

Tags: android, android-studio

tengo un circulo que lo muevo con un onTouch y un rectángulo estático. Quiero identificar cuando el circulo choca con el rectángulo pero no logro hacerlo. Alguien me podría decir que estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias.

Clase Juego:

```
public class Juego extends View implements View.OnTouchListener {

circulo bola = new circulo(this);
rectangulo cuadrado  = new rectangulo(this);
public boolean checkCollision = false;
Paint paint;

public Juego(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    super(context, attributeSet);
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    paint = new Paint();
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    bola.paint(canvas);
    cuadrado.paint(canvas);
}

private boolean collision() {

    if (bola.getBounds().intersect(cuadrado.getBounds()))
        checkCollision = true;

    return checkCollision;
}

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)
{
    circulo.x = (int)event.getX();      
    circulo.y = (int)event.getY();       

    if (collision()){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Colision", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

}

Clase rectangulo:

```
public class rectangulo{

private static final int Y = 200;
private static final int WITH = 400;
private static final int HEIGHT = 400;
int x = 200;
private Juego juego;

public rectangulo(Juego juego) {
    this.juego = juego;
}

public void paint(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    canvas.drawRect(x, Y, WITH, HEIGHT, paint);
}

public Rect getBounds() {
    return new Rect(x, Y, WITH, HEIGHT);
}
```

}

Clase circulo:

```
public class circulo{

private static final int DIAMETER = 50;
int x = 100;
int y = 100;
private Juego juego;

public circulo(Juego juego) {
    this.juego = juego;
}

public void paint(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, DIAMETER, paint);
}

public Rect getBounds() {
    return new Rect(x, y, DIAMETER, DIAMETER);
}
```

}

Comment: Pudiste resolver este problema?

Comment: No, todavía no pude

Answer (score 0):

Para identificar la colisión, simplemente sustituye las vistas.

Esta prueba se realizó con dos `ImageViews`, digamos que en la variable `circulo` tengas la referencia del `View` de `circulo` y en la variable `rectangulo` la referencia del `View` `rectangulo`:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                x = rectangulo.getX() - event.getRawX(); 
                y = rectangulo.getY() - event.getRawY();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                rectangulo.animate().x(event.getRawX() + x).y(event.getRawY() + y).setDuration(0).start();
                Rect rc1 = new Rect();
                circulo.getHitRect(rc1);
                Rect rc2 = new Rect();
                rectangulo.getHitRect(rc2);
                if (Rect.intersects(rc1, rc2)) {
                    // Si chocan haz esto
                } else {
                    // Si no chocan haz esto
                }
                break;


            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                break;

        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Esto detecta la colisión entre dos vistas. `.getHitRect(Rect r)` obtiene un rectangulo imaginario del tamaño de la vista con sus coordenadas. Si ambos rectangulos intersectan matemáticamente, entonces hay una colisión.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. No estoy entendiendo bien el código, no tengo un animate ni un setDuration y el "circulo.getHitRect(rc1);" me lo marca con error.